# android - cannot resolve method findViewById(Int) in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Tags: android, android-studio

I dunno why `Android Studio` cannot resolve that,

this is the piece code of the problem

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  BarChart chart ;
  ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
  ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
  BarDataSet Bardataset ;
  BarData BARDATA ;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1); //error findViewById with red mark
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: did you clean & build the project?

Comment: Got to the Build > Clean Project when its done then again go to the Build > Relbuild Project.

Comment: @TahmidRahman thanks for the suggest , but why its can be like that??

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir it's work sir, but can you tell me why did it happen??

Comment: may be your `R.java` wasn't properly generated

Comment: @dondo: because R.java file is not generated.

Comment: oh, that's was happened, but still i didn't thought about clean and rebuild, -_-

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps:
  1. added dependencies in your app build.gradle.

2. Then initialize the barChart

   BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
3. Check the imports of the bar chart .
4. If above statements are implemented means then clean your project .In android studio sdk at the top Build options is provided in that click on clean project after that wait for sometime to build .Now run your project and check it.

Comment: Please refer this sight for more information about implementing bar chart in http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-chart-example-mp-android-chart-library/